# Angular-mocks $injector doesn't return service, no $get method

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-services, angular-mock

I am attempting to do my best at bdd with Karma and Mocha.  I have created this shell of a service to try to get things going (generated from TypeScript)
[image]

I have created the following test

[image]

I put a break point on the line where the injector gets the service and when it breaks the debugger tells me that scheduleService exists to the injector

[image]

But when I executed the $injector.get method it fails with this error

[image]

What am I doing wrong this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with what I was passing to the factory.  I changed the factory method parameters to

[image]

and now my test is working.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a factory. A factory needs to return an object. Your factory is returning a function, hence the error you are seeing. You are likely needing to use a service instead. The slight difference between a factory and a service is that a factory returns an object provided, while the service returns an object invoked with a `new` to create the instance.

```
angular.module('tsid.scada').service('scheduleService', tsid.scada.scheduleService);
```

Comment: So how do I get a handle on a factory to test it?  Every example I can find uses $injector.get

Comment: You would get it either using standard DI or like you said, using $injector.get